How can i refresh interaction in disnake?
My bot cant play music from queue after 15 minutes when interaction was created. How can i refresh current interaction or extend the duration of current interaction?
I am used many methods and various ways. But I cant fix this nasty bug.
    async def music_play_func(self, bot_inter, author_vc):

    if len(self.queue) >= 1:
                link_or_name = "".join(self.queue[0])
                self.queue.pop(0)
                print("___________________________________")
                print("[log]",link_or_name)
                print("___________________________________")

                with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:

                    try:
                        info = ydl.extract_info(link_or_name, download=False)
                        duration = info['duration']
                        converted_duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds = info['duration'])
                    except KeyError:
                        duration = 300
                        converted_duration = "Live"

                    if 'https://youtu.be' in link_or_name:
                        url_query = urllib3.util.parse_url(link_or_name).path
                        image_index = str(url_query[1:])

                    elif '/shorts' in link_or_name:
                        image_index = link_or_name.lstrip('https://www.youtube.com/shorts/')
                        image_index = image_index[0:10]

                    else:
                        url_query = urllib3.util.parse_url(link_or_name).query
                        image_index = str(url_query[2:])

                embed_player = disnake.Embed(
                    title="Now playing",
                    description=info['title'],
                    colour=0x69ff33
                )
                embed_player.add_field(name="Duration", value=converted_duration, inline=True)
                embed_player.add_field(name="Link", value=link_or_name, inline=True)
                embed_player.set_footer(text=f"Interaction user  {bot_inter.author.name}",
                                        icon_url=f"{bot_inter.author.avatar.url}")
                embed_player.set_image(url=f"https://img.youtube.com/vi/{image_index}/hqdefault.jpg")
                if bot_inter.is_expired():
                    await bot_inter.followup.send(embed=embed_player, delete_after = duration, wait = True)
                else:
                    await bot_inter.send(embed=embed_player, delete_after=duration)

                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                song = info['url']
                author_vc.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.music_play_func(bot_inter, author_vc), loop))


Can you share the method you are using to send the command?

@AlessandroCandeloro
I pasted my code above

the issue you're facing is maybe cause of discord's limitation on interaction responses, which become invalid after 15 minutes.
this means you can't directly update the same interaction after this time, and you need to implement a workaround to maintain the functionality...
you might:

add follow-up messagees for prolonged communication.
periodic refreshes to keep the interaction active.
store context and recreate it as neededd.

you can refer - https://docs.discordnet.dev/faq/int_framework/general.html#:~:text=TimeoutException:%20'Cannot%20respond%20to%20an,false%20in%20the%20%5BDiscordSocketConfig%5D.

Hi! Is this module for C#?
